# CSS - div docked to another div outside wrapper

Tags: css

I have two divs, both are floating left. "Left" div would be left column of the page. "Right" div would be the main content.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
        </div>

        <div id="right">
        </div>

        <div id="docked_div">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 1005px;
}

#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background: red;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}
```

This works fine. Now I have the third div named `docked_div`. This div should be outside the wrapper and on the right side of `right` div (about `20px` from top of `right` div). 
So, the black div now is on the left side, but it should be on the right side and outside the wrapper.

I have tried to set position to relative or absolute in different ways, but I cannot get 
the result I want. I do not have much CSS knowledge on creating layout, so, I would appreciate any suggestions and guidance.

Here is the full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/TA7Rh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 1005px;
    position: relative;
}

#docked_div {
    /*background: url(../images/mazais_fons.png);*/
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 53px;
    height: 212px;
    position: absolute;
    right:-60px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TA7Rh/4/)

change the right position as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
#docked_div {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 212px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 53px;
}
```

This will take the div to be on the right of the main div. Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work like expected. On the webpage the black div is too far to the right (it is not docked to the right div, but it appears on the right of the screen). You cannot see it in fiddle.

Comment: so do you want this docked div to be like your left and right divs that should accomodate and add as a third div? - @renathy